# How to remove part of a file's name in a url

Tags: php, regex, substring, preg-replace, filenames

I need to remove a substring from the start of filename urls.

The substring that I need to remove is always a series of numbers then a hyphen then the word `gallery` then another hyphen.

e.g.  `2207-gallery-` , `2208-gallery-` , `1245-gallery-` , etc.

How can I change this:

```
http://img.pass.com:7710/img.pass.com/img-1/2207-gallery-25171-content_gallery-1428380843.jpg
```

to this:

```
http://img.pass.com:7710/img.pass.com/img-1/25171-content_gallery-1428380843.jpg
```

The substring to be replaced is always different.

Comment: Please, give more specification : is the text to remove is always `2207-gallery-`? or this is just an example ?

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui updated

Comment: So it can be `2208-gallery-` , `1245-gallery-` etc... ?

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui yeap

Comment: @ATIKON please list more details, you need pass it to img element? or you can link, you need only change url ?

Comment: @SebastiaoMarcos only change url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will match 1 or more digits then hyphen then "gallery" then hyphen:

Pattern: ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RmKLcy/1))

```
/\d+-gallery-/
```

PHP Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5062e5c7088718d4870e870414a52871091a364b))

```
$image='http://img.pass.com:7710/img.pass.com/img-1/2207-gallery-25171-content_gallery-1428380843.jpg';
echo preg_replace('/\d+-gallery-/','',$image);
```

Output:

```
http://img.pass.com:7710/img.pass.com/img-1/25171-content_gallery-1428380843.jpg
```

---

Here is your non-regex method:

```
echo substr($image,0,strrpos($image,'/')+1),substr($image,strpos($image,'-gallery-')+9);
```

Answer (score 1):

on `PHP` do this :

```
function renameURL($originalUrl){
    $array1 = explode("/", $originalUrl);
    $lastPart = $array1[count($array1)-1];//Get only the name of the image
    $array2 = explode("-", $lastPart);
    $newLastPart = implode("-", array_slice($array2, 2));//Delete the first two parts (2207 & gallery)
    $array1[count($array1)-1] = $newLastPart;//Concatenate the url and the image name
    return implode("/", $array1);//return the new url
}
//Using the function : 
$url = renameURL($url);
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ff17bc06348830bd0aec2f675babaf9067fa130a)

Comment: While regex can be slower than some non-regex methods, I don't find it very compelling to write so much code and leverage 7 functions instead of a single preg_replace() call.  This is what the PHP designers created regex functions for.

Answer (score 1):

```
function get_numerics ($str) {
    preg_match_all('/\d+/', $str, $matches);
    return $matches[0];
}

$one = 'http://img.pass.com:7710/img.pass.com/img-1/2207-gallery-25171-content_gallery-1428380843.jpg';


$pos1 = strpos($one, get_numerics($one)[3]);
$pos2 = strrpos($one, '/')+1;
echo ( (substr($one, 0, $pos2).substr($one, $pos1)) );
```

See it help you.

Comment: If you are going to use regex, just use it by itself.  If you don't want to use regex for speed reasons or other, don't use any regex functions.  It seems silly to do both in the same method.